# (Xamarin IOS) What are the relationships between XXXDelegate class, IXXXDelegate interface and XXXDelegate_Extention staic class? When to use which?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am a little confused about these types.

Especially XXXDelegate_Extention classes. If I want to implement an optional protocol method, will this XXXDelegate_Extention be useful? Or I always need to subclass the XXXDelegate class?

Thanks!

Comment: Wich one for example?

Comment: Like WebKit.WKNavigationDelegate_Extensions?

Answer (score 1):

Delegates on iOS can have optional methods. Since the interface `IXXDelegate` only **declares the non-optional** functions, `XXXDelegate` only **implements the non-optional** functions. The `XXXDelegate_Extention` **adds the optional** functionsto the delegate (interface). So you can either inherit from `XXXDelegate` or implement `IXXXDelegate` completely on your own. I'd prefer inheriting, unless you really need to have a totally custom implementation.

Extension methods in C# are methods, that can be called like instance methods, but are not declared within the type of this instance.

**Example on Extension methods**

```cs
public class MyClass 
{
    public int Foo(int a)
    {
        return a + 1;
    }
}

public static class MyClassExtension
{
    public static int Bar(this MyClass my, int a)
    {
        return my.Foo(a+1);
    }
}   

var x = new MyClass();
x.Foo(2); // returns 3
x.Bar(2); // returns 4
```

More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: In your first line - is it more accurate to say "protocols on iOS"? Since a delegate is a realization of a protocol. You might also note that when using the interface, the implementation needs to explicitly add the `ExportAttribute` (the IDE usually does this automatically) to the methods so they are exposed to the Objective-C runtime. I would also note that the interfaces are valuable in C# because a class can only inherit from 1 parent, but can implement many interfaces. Allowing 1 class to implement many protocols... The quality of that code is a topic for debate, of course :)